# Keep Duplicates while Using array_diff

Tags: php, arrays

I am using array_diff() to take values out of array1 which are found in array2. The issue is it removes all occurrences from array1, as the PHP documentations makes note of. I want it to only take out one at a time.

```
$array1 = array();
$array1[] = 'a';
$array1[] = 'b';
$array1[] = 'a';

$array2 = array();
$array2[] = 'a';
```

It should return an array with one 'a' and one 'b', instead of an array with just 'b';

Comment: array_unique() returns an array without duplicate values. What I'm trying to do is subtract two arrays. array_diff() does this but it is not exact.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, something that just came to mind. Will work as long as your arrays contain strings:

```
$a = array('a','b','a','c');
$b = array('a');

$counts = array_count_values($b);
$a = array_filter($a, function($o) use (&$counts) {
    return empty($counts[$o]) || !$counts[$o]--;
});
```

It has the advantage that it only walks over each of your arrays just once.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/LUvMHS)**.

**How it works:**

First the frequencies of each element in the second array are counted. This gives us an arrays where keys are the elements that should be removed from `$a` and values are the number of times that each element should be removed.

Then `array_filter` is used to examine the elements of `$a` one by one and remove those that should be removed. The filter function uses `empty` to return `true` if there is no key equal to the item being examined or if the remaining removal count for that item has reached zero; `empty`'s behavior fits the bill perfectly.

If neither of the above holds then we want to return `false` and decrement the removal count by one. Using `false || !$counts[$o]--` is a trick in order to be terse: it decrements the count and always evaluates to `false` because we know that the count was greater than zero to begin with (if it were not, `||` would short-circuit after evaluating `empty`).

Comment: Twice. Once for `array_count_values`, once for `array_filter`. Still more efficient than above, which is O(N^2), though.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Once each, plus of course it does some hash lookups when iterating `$a`. But even so it's still O(N+M).

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: No worries. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Write some function that removes elements from first array one by one, something like:

```
function array_diff_once($array1, $array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $a) {
        $pos = array_search($a, $array1);
        if($pos !== false) {
            unset($array1[$pos]);
        }
    }

    return $array1;
}

$a = array('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b');
$b = array('a', 'b', 'c');

print_r( array_diff_once($a, $b) );
```

Comment: This code has a bug in it.  $pos will, upon first non-match of an item in $array2 in $array1, (which this case isn't included in example), will then return false, which, in the unset() call, will be casted to integer zero, resulting in unset($array1[0]).  To put this another way, this has a very serious flaw, that if there is an element in $array2 that is not present in $array1, then the first element of $array1 will not be considered for the array difference result, which resulted in a very serious bug in my production code because I blindly copied and pasted this, being fairly non-obvious.

Comment: yeah, indeed, I edited my post to include your fix :)