# Extract line or column from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I have a bidimensional PHP array (matrix).

Is there anyway to extract (echo or save into another variable) a line or a column from this matrix without iterating through the elements?

Suppose we have this matrix:

```
A A A B
A A A C
A B C D
```

I want to do something like:

```
display_and_cut_first_line()

//Matrix after this step:    
A A A C
A B C D

display_and_cut_last_column()
//Matrix after this step:
A A A
A B C
```

It only has to work for marginal elements (first/last line, first/last column).
I was thinking of somehow using slice, but didn't manage to do it.

Comment: Upgrade to PHP5.5 as soon as it's available, and get access to the array_column() function - http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-array-column-in-php-5-dot-5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extracting lines is easy: [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) (last line) and [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) (first line) do this for you.

Extracting columns is very easy on PHP 5.5 with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). For earlier versions it would have to be done manually with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or `array_walk` and the pop/shift functions, operating on each line in turn:

```
function extract_last_column(&$array) {
    $column = array();
    array_walk($array, function(&$row) use(&$column) {
        $column[] = array_pop($row);
    });
    return $column;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/xIHwtq)**.

If desired you can generalize this by using `array_slice` instead of `array_pop` and `array_shift` -- but for these particular operations it will be slower.

Comment: Think you might mean `echo array_pop($a);` as OP wants to echo the values cut.

Comment: If you can get it to return the removed section, like `array_pop` et al would, that would be even better, I would have thought.

Comment: @IMSoP: Finished and added a live example. Works like you describe.

Comment: That's a very neat bit of coding :)

Comment: @IMSoP: Thank you. I think I produced [something neater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973365/keep-duplicates-while-using-array-diff/16973544#16973544) yesterday, you might find it amusing.

Comment: Great, but here comes a problem: I do this until the matrix is empty. The problem is that this will not work if the array is uni-dimensional (array_walk will iterate through integer values and try to use array_pop on those, resulting in an error). How can I check if an array is uni-dimensional? (is one line or one column only)

Comment: @Cristy: It should never be uni-dimensional because that would violate the chosen data representation. A single-line matrix should be `[[1, 2, 3]]`, not `[1, 2, 3]`. A single-column matrix could never be uni-dimensional (how would you distinguish that from a single-row?) and in this case it should be `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To get the first row:

```
$arr[0];
```

To get the last column:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
array_column($arr, end($keys));
```

Comment: I'd never heard of `array_column()`, which isn't surprising, as [it's only introduced in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/array_column), which (still!) isn't officially a stable release yet. Interesting to know for future reference though...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$example = array();
$example[0][0] = 'A';$example[0][1] = 'A';$example[0][2] = 'A';$example[0][3] = 'B';
$example[1][0] = 'A';$example[1][1] = 'A';$example[1][2] = 'A';$example[1][3] = 'C';
$example[2][0] = 'A';$example[2][1] = 'B';$example[2][2] = 'C';$example[2][3] = 'D';

$example = display_and_cut_first_line($example);
print_r($example);
/* Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => A
            [2] => A
            [3] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
            [3] => D
        )

)
 */
$example = display_and_cut_last_column($example);
print_r($example);
/* Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => A
            [2] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
        )

)
 */
function display_and_cut_first_line($array){
    array_shift($array);
    return ($array);
}

function display_and_cut_last_column($array){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $data):
        array_pop($data);
        $result[] = $data;
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Partly.

Cutting out a line can be done, using array_splice().

A "column" is not a recognisable entry in the array implementation, so you have to at least iterate the rows, possibly using array_map().