# Find out which items were added and removed in an array

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I'm building application that tells user which are *old* and which are *new* bank notes when I increase sum with *X*. Everything is fine, but I'm wondering **how I can now get list of added and removed items of array?**

```
$old = array(1,5,10);
$new = array(1,5,1);

$added = array_diff($new,$old);
$removed = array_diff($old,$new);
```

And this is what code above returns:

- `$added` is `array()`. Incorrect, it should be `array([2] => 1)`.
- `$removed` is `array([2] => 10)`. Correct.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: value 1 is in both arrays, that's problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $added = array_diff($new,$old);
```

In the above statement, [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) compares `$new` with `$old` and returns the values in `$new` that are *not* present in `$old`. There is no such value, and hence it returns an empty array.

In short, `array_diff()` doesn't work with duplicate values. You will have to write a custom function to achieve this. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973492/1438393):

```
function array_diff_once($array1, $array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $val) {
        if (false !== ($pos = array_search($val, $array1))) {
            unset($array1[$pos]);
        }    
    }
    return $array1;
}
```

You can simply use it the same way you did before:

```
$added   = array_diff_once($new,$old);
$removed = array_diff_once($old,$new);
```

`print_r()` of these arrays would correctly output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
)
Array
(
    [2] => 10
)
```

[**Working demo**](https://eval.in/163187)

Comment: @Downvoter: your explanation could help me improve this answer.

Comment: You don't need to write a function of your own. PHP has a built in function that checks the key of the arrays too.

Comment: @VMai: The OP didn't say anything about the array keys. `$old = array(2, 1); $new = array(1,2);` should produce an empty array, but `print_r(array_diff_assoc($new,$old));` gives `[1, 2]`. Note that the OP didn't say anything about the array keys.

Comment: **+1 and accept** even I discovered little problem when function was used on my quite complex application. Fortunately it was easy to fix: `if($pos !== false){unset($array1[$pos]);}`.

Comment: @petjato: Oh, right. I forgot about that. I've updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check the keys in addition to the values of an array, you should use [array_diff_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)() instead of `array_diff()`:

```
<?php
    $old = array(1,5,10);
    $new = array(1,5,1);

    $added = array_diff_assoc($new,$old);
    $removed = array_diff_assoc($old,$new);

    echo "<pre>\n";     \\ prints array(1) {  [2]=>  int(1) }
    var_dump($added);
    var_dump($removed);
    echo "</pre>\n";
```

?>

Comment: @downvoter: please explain what is wrong with my answer. I think it's a clear answer that explains the difference to the OPs code.

Comment: This also considers the position of the elements in the array while calculating the difference. For example, the OP's array re-arranged: `$old = array(1,5,10); $new = array(5,1,1);` would produce `[5,1,1]`. That is incorrect.