# Arrays difference with duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested-loops

My scenario is this: I have two sets of values that I need to check for differences.  However array_diff does not take into account duplication and thus won't serve my purpose.  Let's say we have the following arrays:

```
$valuesA = array('1.00', '3.00', '1.00', '2.00', '3.00', '1.00');
$valuesB = array('1.00', '3.00', '2.00');
```

Now what I want to do is to run difference check between those two but take duplicate values into account.  In essence after the "diff" the following array would exist:

```
array('1.00', '3.00', '1.00');
```

Now how I managed this was with the following:

```
foreach ($valuesA as $indexA => $valueA) {

    foreach ($valuesB as $indexB => $valueB) {

        if($valueA == $valueB){

            unset($valuesB[$indexB]);
            unset($valuesA[$indexA]);
            continue 2;

        }
    }
}
```

I've always felt that whenever I am writing nested loops like these foreaches I am doing something wrong or that there already exists a better solution.
So my question is this:

> Is there a better way to achieve what these nested foreaches do?

Comment: check out this answer, looks like the solution you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973365/keep-duplicates-while-using-array-diff

Comment: I'm sorry if I am misunderstanding, but should `array('1.00', '3.00', '1.00');` actually read `array('1.00', '3.00', '2.00');` because 1.00, 3.00, and 2.00 are the only unique values, or am I misunderstanding what you are seeking?

Answer (score -1):

```
array_intersect($valuesA, $valuesB);
```