# PHP remove specific item from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like : `[312, 401, 1599, 3]`

With `array_diff( [312, 401, 1599, 3], [401] )` I can remove a value, in my example I removed the value 401.

But if I have this : [312, 401, 401, 401, 1599, 3], how can remove just one time the value 401 ?

It is not important if I remove the first or last value, I just need to remove ONE 401 value, and if I want to remove all 401 values, I have to remove three times.

Thanks !

Comment: what is your current output?? I mean which one to remove?

Comment: my function remove all 401 values, si output is [312,1599,3]

Comment: but which one must remove??

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement somehow. You don't want only *one* occurrence of `401` and you don't care about the index either. Just out of curiosity, what's the end goal here?

Comment: @FrayneKonok He apparently doesn't care: *"It is not important if I remove the first or last value,"*

Comment: Why not just use a simple for each loop with a break statement when the first instance of the value is found. It seems silly to try to come up with some overly complex solution.

Comment: it was solve [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973365/keep-duplicates-while-using-array-diff)

Comment: Well as from your array, I guess you already saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7225070/3933332 why don't you just use it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `array_search` you can get the *first* matching key of the given value, then you can delete it with `unset`.

```
if (false !== $key = array_search(401, $array)) {
  unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `array_intersect` you can retrieve all matching keys at once, which allows you to decide which specific one of them to remove with `unset`.

Answer (score 1):

Search specific key and remove it:

```
if (($key = array_search(401, $array)) !== false) {
   unset($array[$key]); 
}
```

Man PHP:

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

[unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)