# Create a receipt using PHP POST array data

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am learning PHP and trying to make a simple cart/processing script.

I have created the item cart fine, but I am having trouble displaying information in my receipt when a user commits to buying the item(s) in their cart.

To save space/time I have omitted my item lists and the generation of the cart, they can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973682/create-a-one-page-shopping-cart-using-php-session-and-no-sql) if you need it.

Here is the PHP that posts the data to my checkout.php script
**cart.php (Updated to reflect change)**

```
<?php 
session_start(); ?>
<form name="cart" id="cart" action="checkout.php" target='_blank'
    method='post'>
    <h1>Your Cart:</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span class='title'>ID</span></td>
            <td><span class='title'>Product</span></td>
            <td><span class='title'>Price</span></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
// Set a default total
$total = 0;
foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $cartid ) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">
                <?php echo $cartid; ?> <input type="hidden" name="id[]"
                value="<?php echo $cartid; ?>">
            </td>
            <td width="100%">
                <?php echo $title?>
                <input type="hidden" name="title[]" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
            </td>
            <td width="100%">$<?php echo $price;?>
                <input type="hidden" name="prices[]" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    $total += $price;
} // end foreach
?>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>$<?php echo $total; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="submit-button" />
</form>
```

**checkout.php (Updated to reflect change)**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
  echo "  
  <tr>
    <td>$id</td>
    <td>$_POST['titles'][$id]</td>
    <td>$_POST['prices'][$id]</td>
  </tr>
  ";
}

?>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>$</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I cannot seem to get the foreach loop to read the item id, title, or price. I can see the array is being passed using print_r($_POST); but it is indexing each item as a new array item e.g:

```
Array
(
[checkout] => Array
    (
        [0] => A123
        [1] => Item1
        [2] => 1000 
        [3] => Z999
        [4] => Item999
        [5] => 9999  
    )
)
```

How can I post the information in a more meaningful way i.e. associated array. Then use that associated array to display information in a table like format?

**Expected output**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A123</td>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>$1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Z999</td>
    <td>Item999</td>
    <td>$9999</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$10999</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

N.B: This is just a learning exercise so array sanitizing not required, and no SQL.

**Edit:** Updated to reflect @Obsidian Age recommendations, getting parse error now

Comment: you would have to get the price and title from somewhere based on the ID...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your items all have the same `name` attribute in HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkout[]">
```

You would need three different named variables for submission, with one of them being the ID of the particular transaction:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ids[]">
<input type="hidden" name="titles[]">
<input type="hidden" name="prices[]">
```

Then you can loop through each item and add it to a corresponding array:

```
$titles = [];
$prices = [];
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
  array_push($titles, $_POST['titles'][$id]);
  array_push($prices, $_POST['prices'][$id]);
}
```

Or output it directly:

```
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
  $title = $_POST['titles'][$id];
  $price = $_POST['prices'][$id];
  echo "  
  <tr>
    <td>$id</td>
    <td>$title<td>
    <td>$price</td>
  </tr>
  ";
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick feed-back @Obsidian Age !  I changed the cart.php file to have unique names, and the checkout.php to your direct output. I am getting a parse error though?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Hmm, apparently you can't use single quotes for an array when echoing directly. `echo "['a']"` is valid, and `echo "$a[b]"` is valid, but apparently `echo "$a['b']"` is a syntax error. I'll update my answer now to assign them to a variable first.

Comment: Fixed -- the new direct output method should work -- my apologies :)

Comment: No problems at all, thanks so much for the edit @Obsidian Age I also messed up my syntax it turns out i was posting name="id[]" and looking for   ids[] "foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id)". Doh!