# how to get array_diff to ignore duplicates in php?

Tags: php

```
$a1 = ["John", "John", "John", "Steve", "Steve", "John", "Daniel"];
$a2 = ["Steve", "John", "Steve", "John", "Daniel", "John"];
```

How can I make it that array_diff() ignores duplicates treating each string as a separate entity?

The result I'd like from:

```
$result = array_diff($a2, $a1);
```

Would be just "John".

To compare... in Python, I would do:

```
#Names removed:
set(a1) - set(a2)

#Names added:
set(a2) - set(a1)
```

and this would work perfectly. Is there anything equivalent in PHP?

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately after testing it quite a few times, the solution does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973492/4621324

Comment: this works perfectly! thank you.