# Looking for the same chars in two strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, character, similarity

Given two strings, what is the best approach **in PHP** to retrieve the characters which are in common, and those which are not?

For instance, given the two strings:

```
postcard

car
```

I would like to get something like:

```
letters in common: c - a - r
letters not in common: p - o - s - t - d
```

I saw there are word similarity functions which return a numeric value.

However, I would like to *retrieve each single char*.

My approach would be to treat both strings as arrays (using `str_split`) and then check if the elements in the shortest string are present in the longer one (using `in_array`).

```
$arr_postcard = str_split($postcard);
$arr_car = str_split($car);
$notcommon = array();
   if (in_array($arr_postcard, $arr_car) == false){
       array_push($notcommon, $arr_car);
   }
   foreach($notcommon as $k => $v){
      print_r ($v);
   }
```

The code above doesn't seem to work. It returns the values of `$arr_car`.

Maybe there are other ways.

Comment: *My approach would be* a good start, there may be a lot of different ways but you could start with what you already think will solve this.

Comment: I tried to edit my question adding some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973492/4248328

Comment: This [mcve] is ambiguous about how to hand repeated letters.  `car` and `postcard` are words that respectively hold no duplicated letters.  What if one word has a particular letter once and the other word has the same particular letter twice?  What should the result be?  I find this question in need of clarification.  Please [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do so:

```
<?php

$postcard = 'paccoi';
$car = 'coi';

$arr_postcard = str_split($postcard);
$arr_car = str_split($car);


function array_diff_once($array1, $array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $a) {
        $pos = array_search($a, $array1);
        if($pos !== false) {
            unset($array1[$pos]);
        }
    }

    return $array1;
}

$uncommon = count($arr_postcard) >= count($arr_car) ?  array_diff_once($arr_postcard,$arr_car) : array_diff_once($arr_car,$arr_postcard);

echo 'Letters not in common: ' . implode(' - ', $uncommon) . PHP_EOL;

function array_intersect_once($array1, $array2) {
    $array = [];
    foreach($array1 as $a) {
        $pos = array_search($a, $array2);
        if($pos !== false) {
            $array[] = $a;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
$common = count($arr_postcard) >= count($arr_car) ?  array_intersect_once($arr_car,$arr_postcard) : array_intersect_once($arr_postcard,$arr_car);

echo 'Letters in common: ' . implode(' - ', $common) . PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:** https://3v4l.org/lY755 and https://3v4l.org/kK9sE

Note:- you can use `trim()` inside `str_split()` to overcome the problem of string with leading or trailing spaces.

**Reference taken:** [Keep Duplicates while Using array_diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16973492/4248328)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something as the following.
Split the string to obtain each individual character, and flip the keys with the values such that all individual characters are keys. (using [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php#refsect1-function.array-flip-description))

Now we can use the keys with some basic set operations such as the [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php#refsect1-function.array-intersect-key-description) to get the intersection to obtain characters in both strings.
We can apply [array_diff_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-key-description) to get the difference of sets (thus those characters in the first string but not in the other).

```
$s1 = array_flip(str_split('postcard'));
$s2 = array_flip(str_split('car'));

$intersection = array_intersect_key($s1, $s2);
$difference = array_diff_key($s1, $s2);

echo 'Letters in common: ' . implode(' - ', array_keys($intersection)) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Letters NOT in common: ' . implode(' - ', array_keys($difference)) . PHP_EOL;
```

The above was indeed for spitting out unique characters (note set). Below a piece of code I assume is what you are trying to achieve:

```
function outputResult(string $s, bool $inCommon = true)
{
    $result = 'Letters';

    if (!$inCommon) {
        $result .= ' NOT';
    }

    $result .= ' in common: ';
    $result .= !empty($s) ? implode(' - ', str_split($s)) : 'NONE';

    echo $result . PHP_EOL;
}

// Count for both the occurrences of each char.
$s1 = array_count_values(str_split('paccoi'));
$s2 = array_count_values(str_split('coi'));

$mostUniqueChars = $s1;
$leastUniqueChars = $s2;

// For now I assumed the string with most unique characters
// is the one you want to test. Could ofcourse output them both
// ways if you wrap all logic in a function. (note that intersection
// is the same both ways)
if (count($s2) > count($s1)) {
    $mostUniqueChars = $s2;
    $leastUniqueChars = $s1;
}

$intersect = '';
$diff = '';
foreach ($mostUniqueChars as $char => $count) {
    // Get the number of characters in common (and how frequent)
    $common = min($count, ($leastUniqueChars[$char] ?? 0));
    // As an alternative you could add common and difference to an array to keep
    // the counts, but I chose to repeat it and concat it to a string.
    if ($common > 0) {
        $intersect .= str_repeat($char, $common);
    }

    // Calculate the difference between first string and second string
    // in case difference has a value <= 0 then string 2 had more occurrences
    // of the character.
    $difference = $count - ($leastUniqueChars[$char] ?? 0);
    if ($difference > 0) {
        $diff .= str_repeat($char, $difference);
    }
};

// Note that both strings $intersect and $diff contain
// all the characters, you could also output these directly.
outputResult($intersect);
outputResult($diff, $inCommon = false);
```

Outputs:

```
Letters in common: c - o - i
Letters NOT in common: p - a - c
```

Comment: This is an interesting workaround @Remy. I didn't know about `array_intersect_key`.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with repeated letters. Once a letter is stored in the array `$difference`, **all occurences** of that letter are put aside.

Comment: Try with the strings: _paccoi_ and _coi_. You will see the problem.

Comment: With your edited function you solved the issue. I'll need time to go through it and figure out what you did.